# How to use scanf without using an input

Tags: c, scanf

I have a small project in C, in which it says *"tap enter to continue"* (and after that there are instructions). I think we can use `scanf` to do this, but I don't really know how exactly to do it without using an input.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can certainly *read* input without *doing* anything with it.

Comment: You can use `scanf()`... but maybe it's better to use [`getchar()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getchar.html) (in a loop, until <ENTER> is detected). Remember `getchar()` returns a value of type `int`.

Comment: `getchar` will wait for enter key to be pressed

Comment: If you "tap enter", then you are providing input.  There is a big difference between "no input" and "input that is all whitespace".

Comment: Forget `scanf()` use `fgets()` and check if the return is `NULL` (user canceled input with Ctrl+d [or Ctrl+z on windows]) otherwise if the first character of the array filled is `'\n'` (user tapped Enter alone).

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference to :

```
char a = getchar();
if (a == '\n')
{
    printf("This will print if you hit ENTER\n");
}
else
{
    printf("This will print if you hit other than ENTER\n");
}
```

when you hit enter (i.e it will be new line character), hence execution of line with `if statement` will takes place.
Similarly for condition of continuation you can take  `\n` as user input